# Email could not sent using Django and Python

Tags: python, django, email

I have implemented the reset password functionality using Django. Here I am sending the reset password link to registered email and no mail is coming to the inbox. My code is below.

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user474@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user474@gmail.com'
```

registration/password_reset_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h3>Forgot password</h3>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

registration/password_reset_email.html:

```
    {% autoescape off %}
    To initiate the password reset process for your {{ user.get_username }} TestSite Account,
    click the link below:

    {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
window instead.

Sincerely,
The Nuclear Team
{% endautoescape %}
```

My password reset form looks like below.

[image]

Here I could not send the mail to the given email id.

Comment: Can you show us your view for password reset?

Comment: Just read the docs. Your first line of code is wrong. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: It does not send mail because the mail is printed to console. Like you configured it.

Comment: @Wencakisa : I attched the screen shot for the form.

Comment: @satya view mean views.py code where your reset action

Comment: I have not done anything inside views.py Its all inbuilt in Django.

Comment: @allcaps : Ok,I change it to `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` but its throwing error like `SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`.

Comment: Are you sure that Gmail accepts mail with this config? Can you send mail to gmail with those settings from another client? Do you get the same error there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yiu need replace:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
#                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
#                                   ^^^^^^
```

more info here: [email-backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#obtaining-an-instance-of-an-email-backend)

Comment: I did it but still this `SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.` error coming.

Comment: does you input correct email? did your redirect on reset done?

Comment: It worked I just changed `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have on your views something like:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
email.send()
```

Also you need to unlock captcha on your gmail account:
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha